# Karamata's Abelian/Tauberian Theorem in the complex plane

Tags: cv.complex-variables, sequences-and-series, power-series, tauberian-theorems

The following result is well known (a particular case of Karamata's Tauberian Theorem for Power Series in Corollary 1.7.3 of Regular variation by Bingham, Goldie & Teugels):

Fix $c, \rho>0$. If $(a_n)_{n \geq 1}$ is a sequence of nonnegative real numbers and the power-series $A(s)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n s^n$ converges for $s \in [0,1)$, then the following are equivalent:

(i) $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k \sim c n^\rho / \Gamma(1+\rho)$ as $n \to \infty$

(ii) $A(s) \sim c /(1-s)^\rho$ as $s \uparrow 1$.

**Question.** Assume that (i) and (ii) above are in force. Is it true that
$$\label{1}\tag{1}  A(z) \sim c/(1-z)^\rho \qquad \textrm{as} \qquad z \in \mathbb{C}, |z|<1?$$

It is not too difficult to check that when $z \to 1$ in a [Stolz region (i.e. in a cone)](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/StolzAngle/) we indeed have $A(z) \sim c/(1-z)^\rho$.  The question is whether this also holds along tangential limits.

I am aware that in the somewhat related context of Abel-Stolz's theorem, there are [counterexamples](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/394773/in-search-for-a-counterexample-related-to-the-abel-stolz-theorem) where tangential limits do not exist.  But in these counterexamples the coefficients do not satisfy the nonnegativity condition, so I am wondering if the condition $a_n \geq 0$ implies \eqref{1}.

*Edit:* **Question':** Does \eqref{1} hold if one assumes the stronger condition $a_n \sim c' n^{\rho-1}$ as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: If $\rho=1$ and $a_n=1+o(1)$, does it follow that $A(z)\sim 1/(1-z)$, in other words that $\sum b_nz^n=o(1/(1-z))$ whenever $b_n=o(1)$? Does not look probable.

Comment: Ah, indeed, the series $
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^{3^n}-z^{2\cdot3^n}}{n}
$ from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2787213/counter-example-for-stolz-sector-in-complex-version-of-abels-theorem) gives a counterexample !

Comment: ...or simply $\sum z^{3^n}/n$, or $2^n$ instead of $3^n$